# How to use thrust to copy values with the same keys from one array to another?

Tags: c++, cuda, thrust

I have a sparse histogram with keys as bins and values as count. I would like to use the keys and counts in the histogram to create another key value array. The keys in this array are bins but repeated count times, and in the end each key would have value equal to the corresponding count. Keys in both the histogram and the array are sorted in ascending order.

For example if the histogram looked like this:

```
    Key/Bins:       0 2 4 5 6 7
    Values/Counts:  3 2 1 4 2 3
```

The key array whose values I would like to find looks like this:

```
 Key:     0 0 0 2 2 4 5 5 5 5 6 6 7 7 7
```

After populating the values using the histogram the new key-value array 
would look like this:

```
   Key:     0 0 0 2 2 4 5 5 5 5 6 6 7 7 7
   Values:  3 3 3 2 2 1 4 4 4 4 2 2 3 3 3
```

I can do this using loops and checking if two keys are the same but is there an efficient way to do this using Thrust?

Thanks!

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you are asking.  You have a data set in your first  gray block and from that you want to produce the data set depicted in your 3rd gray block?

Comment: Yes, I have the data set in the first gray block but only the keys array from the second block. Using those three arrays I want to produce data depicted in the 3rd.Sorry for the confusion. I will edit the question to make it more clear.

Comment: are there ever zero values in the `Values/Counts` field?  Stated another way, do you ever have situations where some values in the `Key/Bins` field don't show up in the `Key` array?

Comment: No, there are no zero values in the counts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possible method:

1. use `thrust::transform` using two offset versions of the `key` array to mark the beginning of each segment

   ```
   Key:     0 0 0 2 2 4 5 5 5 5 6 6 7 7 7
   seg:     0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0
   ```
2. with the beginning of each segment marked, perform a `thrust::inclusive_scan` to turn the segment markers into a set of lookup indices

   ```
   Key:     0 0 0 2 2 4 5 5 5 5 6 6 7 7 7
   seg:     0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0
   idx:     0 0 0 1 1 2 3 3 3 3 4 4 5 5 5
   ```
3. these lookup indices can then be used with a `thrust::permutation_iterator` to copy the indexed values from the values/counts array into the desired output

   ```
   Key:     0 0 0 2 2 4 5 5 5 5 6 6 7 7 7
   seg:     0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0
   idx:     0 0 0 1 1 2 3 3 3 3 4 4 5 5 5
   Val:     3 3 3 2 2 1 4 4 4 4 2 2 3 3 3
   ```

Here is a worked example:

```
$ cat t1299.cu
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/zip_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/permutation_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/transform.h>
#include <thrust/remove.h>
#include <thrust/copy.h>
#include <iostream>

struct my_remove
{
  template <typename T>
  __host__ __device__
  bool operator()(const T &t)
  {
    return (thrust::get<0>(t) == 0);
  }
};

struct my_cmp
{
  template <typename T>
  __host__ __device__
  int operator()(const T &t)
  {
    if (thrust::get<0>(t) != thrust::get<1>(t)) return 1;
    return 0;
  }
};

using namespace thrust::placeholders;

int main(){

  int kb[] = {0,2,4,5,6,7};
  int vc[] = {3,2,1,4,2,3};
  int key[] = {0,0,0,2,2,4,5,5,5,5,6,6,7,7,7};
  int kbsize = sizeof(kb)/sizeof(int);
  int keysize = sizeof(key)/sizeof(int);

  thrust::device_vector<int> dkb(kb, kb+kbsize);
  thrust::device_vector<int> dvc(vc, vc+kbsize);
  thrust::device_vector<int> dkey(key, key+keysize);
  thrust::device_vector<int> dval(keysize);
  thrust::copy(dkey.begin(), dkey.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ","));
  std::cout << std::endl;

  //first remove any zero count values from kb/vc

//  thrust::remove_if(thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(dvc.begin(), dkb.begin())), thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(dvc.end(), dkb.end())), my_remove());

  // next, mark the segments in the key array

  thrust::transform(thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(dkey.begin(), dkey.begin()+1)), thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(dkey.end()-1, dkey.end())), dval.begin()+1, my_cmp());

  // prefix sum to generate lookup indices
  thrust::device_vector<int> didx(keysize);
  thrust::inclusive_scan(dval.begin(), dval.end(), didx.begin());

  // use lookup indices to populate values vector

  thrust::copy(thrust::make_permutation_iterator(dvc.begin(), didx.begin()), thrust::make_permutation_iterator(dvc.begin(), didx.end()), dval.begin());

  // display results

  thrust::copy(dval.begin(), dval.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ","));
  std::cout << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
$ nvcc -arch=sm_35 -o t1299 t1299.cu
$ ./t1299
0,0,0,2,2,4,5,5,5,5,6,6,7,7,7,
3,3,3,2,2,1,4,4,4,4,2,2,3,3,3,
$
```

A typical example of thrust optimization is to look for "fusion" of operations.  In this case, since we have a transform operation immediately followed by an inclusive scan, a simple example of fusion would be to replace these with a [`thrust::transform_inclusive_scan`](https://thrust.github.io/doc/group__transformed__prefixsums.html)

Comment: It works! Thank you. I had looked up some set operations on thrust after posting the question and found the function _set_intersection_by_key_. Is this another approach to this problem? Thanks again!

Comment: It's not obvious to me how to use set intersection to solve this, but you may have some ideas.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are doing table lookup in GPU. Here's an implementation using cuckoo hash on GPU with CUDA. 
https://github.com/shixing/cuckoo/tree/master

The building process is implemented on CPU:

> create_hash_cpu(h_keys,h_values,h_key_1,h_key_2,h_value_1,h_value_2, N, EMPTY_KEY);

The lookup process is on GPU:

> cuckoo_lookup<<<(M+255)/256, 256>>>(d_keys_lookup, d_values_lookup, d_key_1, d_value_1, d_key_2, d_value_2, M, N, EMPTY_KEY, EMPTY_VALUE);